# how to dynamically generate methods for proxy class?

Tags: python, metaprogramming

I have a object like:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self,instance):
        self.instance = instance
```

with

```
>>> instance = SomeOtherObject()
>>> f = Foo(instance)
```

I want to be able to do

```
>>> f.some_method()
```

and have the following call,

```
>>> f.instance.some_method()
```

For complicated reasons, I cannot simply chain the attributes as in the above. I need to dynamically create an instance function on `f` with the same function signature as the embedded `instance`. That is, I need to do `f.some_method()` and then dynamically create the `some_method` instance-method for the `f` instance when it is invoked that pushes `some_method` down to the embedded object `instance`.

I hope that made sense. This is for Python 2.7. Any help appreciated.

Comment: To create a `Foo` in your code, one must pass an instance of something else as an argument, so `f = Foo()` would cause an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write a `__getattr__()` method for your proxy class. This will be called when an attribute is accessed that doesn't exist on your instance. Return your contained object's attribute of the same name (or a wrapper if you insist, but there's no need if you just want to call the contained object's method and don't need to do anything else). Bonus: works with data as well as callables.

```
def __getattr__(self, name):
    return getattr(self.instance, name)
```

Does not work with `__` methods, however.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the `wrapt` module. It is purpose built for creating transparent object proxy where you can selectively override certain aspects of the wrapped object. For example:

```
class Test(object):
    def some_method(self):
        print 'original'

import wrapt

proxy = wrapt.ObjectProxy(Test())
proxy.some_method()

print

class TestWrapper(wrapt.ObjectProxy):
    def some_method(self):
        self.__wrapped__.some_method()
        print 'override'

wrapper = TestWrapper(Test())
wrapper.some_method()
```

This yields:

```
original

original
override
```

The default behaviour of the `ObjectProxy` class is to proxy all method calls or attribute access. Updating attributes via the proxy will also update the wrapped object. Works for special `__` methods and lots of other stuff as well.

For details on `wrapt` see:

- http://wrapt.readthedocs.io

Specific details on the object proxy can be found in:

- http://wrapt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wrappers.html

There are so many traps and pitfalls with doing this correctly, so recommended you use `wrapt` if you can.